# Android. Save file into shared directory on device

Tags: android, file, stream

I can save some data into file

```
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(openFileOutput("FILENAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
    val data = byteArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(data)
    byteArrayOutputStream.close()
```

But I want to save it not into my app directory, but into some shared folder.

Comment: On Android 9 and below you can use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). However, [you cannot write there by default on Android 10 and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) to allow the user to choose where you should write your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt")
FileOutputStream(file).use {
  it.write("ASDFGHJKL".toByteArray())
}
```

U have also to ask run time permission

```
if (PERMISSION_GRANTED != ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
} else {
  createFile()
}
```

...

```
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                createFile()
            } else {
                // разрешение не получено
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work with android 10 and higher. Permissions are not used much anymore. I am currently struggling to redo all of my code with the shared storage and content providers :(  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access External Storage then Try this android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Okey, I use `FileOutputStream(File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt"))` And it works, file is created. But when I write data, it is empty ((

Comment: `when I write data, it is empty`. Do you mean: `when I read data, it is empty` ? With what do you read the file? What is the file size in bytes?

Comment: I don't read this file. I just find it in "My files" on my device and it's 0 b